# Mixtures and alligations - Acid concentration

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

From a vessel containing $1$ litre of pure acid, $100$ ml pure acid was drawn out in each of the beakers A and B.
The acid in both the beakers was diluted by adding water in different proportions. After that, the contents of A
and B were added back to the vessel. The concentration of acid in the vessel now is $80$%. Had the contents of
beakers A and B be mixed with each other instead of adding into the vessel, what would be the concentration
of acid in that mixture?

A. $28.57$%

B. $55.55$%

C. Insufficient data

**My approach:-**

Initially vessel=1000 ml

After transferring the contents,

Vessel=800 ml
Beaker A=100 ml
Beaker B=100 ml

Now beaker A and B are diluted, let their new concentrations be x% and y% respectively, and their combined concentration of 200 ml be a%

Now this 200 ml solution is being transferred back to the vessel of a% concentration

so if I apply alligation over here ,  I would get the following ratio

(100-80) / (80-a) = 1/4

giving a=0 %, and this the thing being asked in question too, but I cant find such option here , and also a=0 looks weird too as how can we get 0% acid concentration on mixing 2 acid solutions

Please guide me where I am going wrong

Comment: I would bypass any effort about "their new concentrations" of beakers $A,B$ since these wind up being lumped together (either in the adding back to the original vessel or in being mixed together).  Instead focus on how much water would have been added.  We know it was enough to reduce the one liter of "pure acid" in the original vessel to $80$% concentration.  So how much water would that have been?

Comment: The answer is 44.4444%, I believe. Let $x$ ml be the total volume of water added....

Answer (score 1):

I think answer-B is a typo and should be $44.44\%$.

The acid put into A and B is returned so contents of the original container
$(\space 1\text{ liter })\space $
plus the water-added are what make $\space 80\%.\quad$

$$\dfrac{1000\space\text{ml}}
{80\%}=1,250\space\text{ml}$$
The combined volume of $A + B +\text{water}$ is $\space 200+250=450 \text{ ml}.$

$$\dfrac{200}{450}=44.44\%$$